# Apply stucco directly to cement board

Tags: outdoor, exterior, stucco, cement-board

I'm fixing stucco on an old house and it appears as though they literally just added stucco onto cement board with asphalt kraft paper in between. I have to remove a piece to add in new cement board that broke on the back. Can I just stucco directly onto the cement board without a mesh? I didn't know this was possible, but apparently the builders did it! Also, can I forgo the paper? It doesn't seem to be doing much if anything at all - water doesn't sit on this surface but rather beads off as it is hanging (the area in question is a soffit).

http://www.imgur.com/fj2BGHg crude drawing :)

Comment: How thick is the existing stucco layer? Also, is there an air gap behind the cement board, and are there moisture problems on the other side? This seems like an odd assembly to me, but if it's working...

Comment: id say the existing stucco layer is about a 1/8th in thick, there are joists behind the cement board with about 1/2 foot from the back of the cement board to the plywood and no apparent moisture problems. this was done all around the house.

Comment: Is that plywood the inner surface of the soffit...?

Comment: it looks like this if it helps: http://www.imgur.com/fj2BGHg